# Case statement error not able to add a column value with statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to trigger in output if profile date is changed so  want to add old date as well but it is giving error

```
Select Name,
       case when a.PROFILE_START != b.PROFILE_START then 'Trigger: Start Date Changed'+ b.PROFILE_START  
       else '' end
from a 
join b on a.name = b.name
```

This code is giving error

> The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: you have to cast b.PROFILE_START column as varchar then concatenate with other string.

Comment: Yes, please tag the request with your DBMS. In most DBMS `+` is for adding values (two numbers, a datetime and an interval, ...), not for concatenating strings. And then, you are not even concatenating strings, but a string and a date. Does your DBMS implicitly convert the date to a string in this context?

Comment: Use `FORMAT` or `CONVERT` to get a string representation from your profile date column.

Comment: FYI its a `case` *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Name ,
       case when a.PROFILE_START != b.PROFILE_START then 'Trigger: Start Date Changed '+ CAST(b.PROFILE_START  AS VARCHAR(100))
       else '' end
from a 
  join b  on a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `concat()`:

```
Select Name,
       (case when a.PROFILE_START <> b.PROFILE_START
             then concat('Trigger: Start Date Changed ', b.PROFILE_START)
             else ''
        end)
from a join
     b
     on a.name = b.name;
```

However, when working with dates, I think you should be explicit about the format using `CONVERT()` or `FORMAT()`.  I would recommend ISO standard formats:

```
Select Name,
       (case when a.PROFILE_START <> b.PROFILE_START
             then concat('Trigger: Start Date Changed ', 
                         convert(varchar(255), b.PROFILE_START, 121)
                        )
             else ''
        end)
from a join
     b
     on a.name = b.name;
```

You can peruse the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you prefer another format.